# Can you cache sound files in an iOS web app using a manifest or Web Storage?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, web-applications, ios5

When I add my beep-23.mp3 file to the cache manifest, the sound effect no longer works on or offline.  Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

The audio is within an html file as:

```
function playBEEP() { if (navigator.platform == "iPad" || navigator.platform == "iPhone" || navigator.platform == "iPod") { Beep.play(); } }
if (navigator.platform == "iPad" || navigator.platform == "iPhone" || navigator.platform == "iPod") {
    var Beep = document.createElement('audio');
    Beep.setAttribute('src', 'beep-23.mp3');
}
```

Accessed via:

```
$("#mybutton,#anotherbutton").each(function() {
    $(this).bind("touchstart",function(e){ 
            playBEEP();
    });
});
```

`<html manifest='index.manifest'>` makes the audio stop working when beep-23.mp3 is listed...

**UPDATE:** Could [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) be used instead of the cache manifest to store the audio??

Comment: Did you check that the manifest's content was actually downloaded? Maybe it is just a typo...

Comment: Without knowing more about WHAT you are doing, it's really hard to say whether it's your code or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE for iOS 6:**

> This is all fixed in iOS 6. You can cache an audio file and play it via javascript without user input.
>   ***shaun5*** Nov 7 '12 at 0:58

---

Even though it should work and there are no specifications (W3C, Apple) which say it shouldn't, I tested some scenarios and it seems like Safari on iOS is just refusing to cache the sound files.

Safari is loading the audio file (but not the index.html) every time I reload the page, so caching is apparently not working correct regardlessly of file size.

**After some research: It looks like it's not possible to cache audio files. So you may file a bug at Apples [bugtracker](https://bugreport.apple.com/)**.

Here's my code to prove my results:

*index.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html lang="en-US" manifest="audio.appcache">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>Cached audio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Cached audio</h1>
    <audio controls autobuffer>
      <source src="sample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

*audio.appcache:*

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2012-02-23:v1

# explicitly cached
CACHE:
index.html
sample.mp3
```

*.htaccess:*

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
```

**EDIT**

I also tried using data URIs but, that Safari keeps refusing the audio data. So I think it's not possible to cache audio …

```
<?php
  function data_uri( $file ) {
    $contents = file_get_contents( $file );
    $base64   = base64_encode( $contents );
    return ( 'data:audio/mpeg;base64,'.$base64 );
  }
?>
...
<audio controls autobuffer>
  <source src="<?php echo data_uri('sample.mp3'); ?>" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
...
```

**EDIT 2**

Great idea, but it looks like it's not working … Safari for OS X -> ok; Safari for iOS -> still the same problem as we had before.

```
<?php
  function base_64_string( $file ) {
    $contents = file_get_contents( $file );
    return base64_encode( $contents );
  }
?>
...
<audio controls autobuffer>
  <source id="sound-src" src="sample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
...
<script>
  (function(){
    var sound;
    if ( localStorage.getItem('cachedSound')) {
      sound = localStorage.getItem('cachedSound');
    }
    else {
      sound = "<?php echo base_64_string('sample.mp3'); ?>";
      localStorage.setItem('cachedSound',sound);
    }
    document.getElementById("sound-src").src='data:audio/mpeg;base64,' + sound;
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer made me think of a possible solution, see my updated question.

Comment: I think you have to wait for the user to play the file before Mobile Safari will download the file, so I would think you would have to wait to save it to local storage.

Comment: @shaun5 I debugged using console.log and the data is loaded immediately after the page is rendered. So that can't be the problem …

Comment: Does the audio play in Mobile Safari?  It has been my experience that once the audio is listed on the cache manifest, it never plays online or offline.

Comment: @shaun5 That's true, so you have to remove it. I think caching audio is just not wanted, so it's best to keep sound files away from the manifest file.

Comment: This is all fixed in iOS 6.  You can cache an audio file and play it via javascript without user input.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already you have to make sure that URL paths are absolute or relative to the .manifest and not the actual webpage.

There is also a limit to the size of the actual component that you are trying to cache currently at 4MB.

The total cache limit is 5MB.

I'm also pretty sure you can not cache audio and video files.

Comment: All three files (html, mp3, manifest) are in the same directory.  The total and individual file sizes are under the limits.  Do you have any experience or documentation to support your 'pretty sure'?

Comment: @shaun5 I've done a lot of reading on the apple devs site and there is nothing to say that you can. Also I've tried doing that myself too, everything cached except the video. I didn't have a audio file on it though. By process of elimination I'd have to assume you can't.

Answer (score -1):

Apple do not support playing audio via safari, this is intentional to prevent people using online domains to store you music without paying for them and using you iPod/iPhone to play them. It's apples way of trying to make you pay for music. Sorry guys.

Comment: This answer seems to directly contradict the question and other answers.